# FileObject->FileName not returning complete path of a file

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver

I'm a newbie in Driver developing field. I'm trying to display path of every file which opens. I'm using following line for displaying path.

```
PFILE_OBJECT pFileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;
DbgPrint("File Name : %wZ\n", &pFileObject->FileName);
```

But it is not displaying complete path.

`File Name : \Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\cmd commands.txt`

it should be like this:

`File Name : C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\cmd commands.txt`

Drive name (e.g C:, D:) is missing, is any thing wrong...?

Comment: should decide if you think you are programming in C or C++, and since your question is OS specific you should also tag your question with that. (some sort of windows I suppose)

Comment: My question is driver specific, which is tagged...

Comment: driver is very generic and could also apply to linux or OS X or whatever.

Comment: ok, now windows tag is added...kindly guide me is any other tag needed...?

Comment: [IoVolumeDeviceToDosName](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=50140)

Answer (score 1):

The `FileName` just contains the name of the file. The volume information is described in the `Vpb` field.

Comment: Thanks for you response, can you please tell me how to use this, i'm getting null pointer exception on `pFileObject->Vpb->VolumeLabelLength`

Comment: Hmm, maybe I got that wrong. It looks like FileName is relative to RelatedFileObject. Only valid during IRP_MJ_CREATE  processing.

Comment: Try using `IoVolumeDeviceToDosName(pFileObject->Vpb->RealDevice, buf)` to get the drive letter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550422(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @sergmat You seem to know what you are talking about. You could helpfully answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i'm getting `pFileObject->Vpb null` but this `&pFileObject->FileName` returns the correct path (incomplete path).